# tqdm.tqdm overrides arg position=int upon completion in gnome-terminal

Tags: python, bash, tqdm

[image: Preview]

EDIT : Caused by `bash` and not `tqdm`

Three download tasks are added with `threading.Thread` and the position for each of them is specified.
Upon completion of a task, it moves to the top irrespective of what position it was assigned, and the task at the bottom shifts to the new line and interrupts with the next input of the terminal upon completion.

```py
    with tqdm(
        total=total,
        unit="B",
        unit_scale=True,
        unit_divisor=1024,
        leave=True,
        ncols=100,
        colour="green",
        position=index,
        dynamic_ncols=True,
        desc=f"{index}",
    ) as progress_bar, open(filelocation, "wb") as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):
            progress_bar.update(len(chunk))
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)
```

PS: In the figure you can see task `2` has taken two jumps from its place.

Comment: Might be [a bug in tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/1305).

Comment: Works fine on `fish` terminal, it has something to do with `bash`

Comment: It's also possible that it has something to do with that fancy prompt. Try setting `PS1='$ '` and see if that helps. Even if it does, I'd still consider it an issue with tqdm.

Comment: Persists with `bash --noprofile --norc` as well.

Comment: Maybe related to: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/1000